# Remove adf.ly malware

Tags: windows, malware, antimalware

A malware redirects my page browser to adf.ly website page that requires me to wait 5 seconds and then click skip ads to get to my page. I tried the following things:

- I scanned my PC with most of malware program
- Reset Chrome, mozilla and all browser
- Removed cookies and temp

Finally I changed my windows and the first thing before setting up any thing checked this with internet explorer and was shocked that the malware still infected my PC.

Please i need quick help. I can’t work or search for anything.

Comment: Back up your data and reinstall the OS.

Comment: i reinstall my windows and first thing before setup any thing checked this with internet explorer and shocked that malware still infected my PC

Comment: I don't think that's a malware.The sites you visit intentionally redirect you to adf.ly to display ads.

Comment: it's redirect most sites and some of them developed by me

Comment: If you reinstalled it properly (from clean install media) then it may be your router tampering with HTTP requests or returning fake DNS records to redirect you to the ads.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your browser settings. Make sure your home page is google.com ( for example). After that, download adblock, with that plugin you can block sites, ads, etc... Add adf.ly to blacklist, and i belive problem will be solved.

Comment: While this is a good preventative measure, I don't believe it would remove an already existing piece of malware. Good advice outside of that fact though.

Comment: If it is malware, user should try to see where it is executed, malware should be somewhere inside all running processes, when he find it, he would be able to remove it manually. Also, if user reinstalled OS, malware shouldn't be there. He can try again with reinstalling OS, just this time, he can try to delete all partitions and start making another ones. One of these things should solve problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, i checked all setting , scanned with most malware program and change OS several time but all not solve this , there is another point when i linked chrome in mobile with same account in PC this redirect shown also i mobile so create another user in chrome , remove all extension and reset to default but not affected anyway . i can't create new partition because i have very important and huge data in my hard disk , any advice about this